# Python: Name "from" as parameter throws Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am working on API and I really cannot rename variable name to process things fast but I cannot make run the code(Python 3.11).

The problem:

```
def __init__(self, from: str = None)
    self.from = from
```

when I try to run this piece of beautifully written gem, I got an error.

```
def __init__(self, from: str = None
                   ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even the pylance had problem with the syntax but I manage to fix it with `# type: ignore` at the beginning of the script.

Any advice?

Editor: VSCode

I have tried Google but didn't help much. :)

Comment: `from` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an identifier name. Period. Your only choice is to use a different signature (rename the parameter, or accept a dictionary instead?)

Comment: As a side note, `name: str = None` is strictly speaking a type error. `name: Optional[str] = None` or `name: str | None = None` would be more correct

Comment: Thank you Brian, you didn't make me happy. Thank you

Comment: @Brian I think a good argument could be made that `foo: SomeType = None` is very clear, ergonomic, and not particularly error-prone, while `foo: SomeType | None = None` is redundant boilerplate that wastes more time (including, most importantly, time of people reading the code) than it recoups in "yes I really did mean `None` is allowed here, that wasn't a mistake" value. (In other words, a good argument could be made that a static type analyzer should absolutely accept `= None` at the declaration site as equivalent to `| None = None`.)

Comment: okay, I fixed the name but my recursions don't seem so beautiful like before -*moisturized*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't very clear, but `from` is a reserved keyword

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

```py
    ...
except Exception as ex:
    raise ValueError("oops") from ex
```

```py
def my_generator(some_iter):
    ...
    yield from some_iter
```

```py
from foo import bar
```

If you *must* to keep the name (say, frontending some other frozen frozen API), you could extract it from `**kwargs`

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._from = kwargs["from"]
```

You may also have to be careful creating instance of the class

```py
AwkwardFromArgClass(**{"from": "from value"})
```

Comment: A good practice for alternative parameter names instead of "from" is to answer: *what* does this argument represent/contain? For example, an `IPv4Address` class which can take a string (`IPv4('8.8.8.8')`) can use `address` instead of `from` as the parameter name.

Comment: When the keyword is really the best word, [PEP-8 recommends *appending* a single *suffix* `_`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments): "If a function argument’s name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus `class_` is better than `clss`. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)"

Comment: ah, it's a bit religious for such a class, but I prefer the `_` prefix here to help it be clearer that `_from` is a internal member (still avoiding `SyntaxError`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/ .. but practically, something like your suggestion of "address" or "don't do that" will be much better! .. and perhaps most practically, a style like using `kwargs["from"]` provides a great opportunity to accept _both_ an old and new value optionally (perhaps via `KeyError`), inject a warning, and ultimately hope to transition to a friendlier name!

Comment: Yes, when it's a *private attribute* it should be a prefix `_` - the quoted PEP 8 guideline for suffix `_` applies to *public parameters* (and I would say to *public attributes* and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `from` as an argument name because is a default syntax used to import modules like `from math import sin` to import only the sin function.

Try renaming it `from_` with F2